# Unit test not fire breakpoint

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, xunit

I want to create unit test with theory attribute and custom data member which read a file.
After creating custom data member debug not hit breakpoint (set on start of GetData method). I have no idea why :/
Code of custom data member

```
public class TestDataFilesReader : DataAttribute
    {
        private const string PARENT_FOLDER = "Data";
        private readonly string _filePath;

        public TestDataFilesReader(string filePath)
        {
            _filePath = $"{PARENT_FOLDER}/{filePath}";
        }

        public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(testMethod);

            var currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var fullPath = Path.GetRelativePath(currentDir, _filePath);

            if (!File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Couldn't find a given file.", Path.GetFileName(fullPath));
            }

            // 1. get file extension
            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);


            // only fake data
            return Enumerable.Empty<object[]>();
        }
```

Code of unit test

```
[Theory]
        [TestDataFilesReader("JsonFilesData/AccountService_RegisterUser_Data.json")]
        public void RegisterUser_ForGivenData_ReturnsTrue(string test)
        {
            ...
        }
```

.csproj of unit test project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.18.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Data\JsonFilesData\AccountService_RegisterUser_Data.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

File is existing in folder (I checked it).
A bit funny is that when I change a path within calling TestDataFilesReader on incorrect path breakpoint is hit

I tried:

1. Run VS as Admin
2. Checked whether file exists
   I expect:
   Read file

Comment: Are you able to hit a breakpoint set at the start of `RegisterUserAsync_ForGivenData_ReturnsTrueAsync`? You also have "async" in the title, but the method is not async.

Comment: @gunr2171 I've changed name of unit test method. I've set breakpoint at the beginning of RegisterUser_ForGivenData_ReturnsTrue, but still not hit breakpoint

Comment: @gunr2171 Additionally I've added System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); to constructor of custom data member and then breakpoint is hit.
Within output I have plenty of line with"Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled" string. What does it mean?

Comment: Because optimization might change the code created by the compiler, it is recommended that you debug your application and then optimize your code. This also can cause the breakpoint not hit. turn off the Code Optimization and try again

Comment: @SimLab, Just My Code is a Visual Studio debugging feature that automatically steps over calls to system, framework, and other non-user code. this has nothing to do with your breakpoint not hit

Comment: The GetData method is returning an empty Enumerable so there is not really any test to debug, is there?